# Get file/folder attributes from IShellFolder using DWORD attribute

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, attributes, dword

I am very new to C++ specially MS C++ (for windows stuff)

I want to display overlay icons on the folders.

I am some how succeeded in that because of few examples on the net.

I am trying to get and manipulate the file/folder attributes so that I can create a criteria to show the overlay icon.

I am having a hard time in understanding the DWORD stuff that how could I retrieve the information from it about the file/folder (if there is any), I am talking about `IShellIconOverlayIdentifier::IsMemberOf`  method.

```
    HRESULT IsMemberOf(
  [in]  PCWSTR pwszPath,
  DWORD dwAttrib
);
```

How could I know if its a folder or its writable or not bla bla... (from dwAttrib).

It says (dwAttr in [IsMemberOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation) that

> The object's attributes

Does it DWORD really contains all the attributes of a file/folder?

If I have to get it from `IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf` method, then how i can achieve that.

I am quit lean towards java so i hope i will just need to do this overlay stuff.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

IShellIconOverlayIdentifier is implemented by shell extensions and you generally don't use this interface directly, the shell calls it deep inside its namespace/IShellFolder implementation.

When you have a IShellFolder interface and a child pidl you call it like this:

```
SFGAOF icareabout = SFGAO_COMPRESSED|SFGAO_ENCRYPTED;
hr = pShellFolder->GetAttributesOf(1,&childpidl,&icareabout);
//Check hr
if (SFGAO_COMPRESSED&icareabout) ...
```

If you only have a absolute pidl, call [SHBindToParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first.

If you only have a regular path, call [SHParseDisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it can give you the flags (Remember to free the pidl) The same thing can be achieved by calling [SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES.